# Unable to see Listener response body data in JMeter on MAC OS

Tags: macos, jmeter

I set up a simple POST request, with it's listener. I know it's working because the reponse data can be displayed in POSTMAN. The issue is that the View results three shows it's a 200 Code, but it doesnt show the Body data (Where i should extract the JSON expressions I need), in Mac OS there's a special configuration i need to run? I'm unable to find the jmeter.properties file also.

JMeter doesn't show response data, JSON or text.

[image]

Example of the response ():

Response code: 200.
Response message: OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue earlier and already updated another post.
For me, I had to switch to using Java version 8, but version 9 may also work.  In my case, version 9 did not work, but using version 8 did.
[image]