# Unable to see Response Body in JMeter, View Results Tree listener

Tags: jmeter, listener, performance-testing

When I run a Http Request, to a page that should return a response body (I know it's working because I already tried in Postman). When I execute the sampler it's sends a 200 OK code, but the response body in the *View Results Tree* Listener, is empty. Why does this happen?

I use MAC OS, and I installed JMeter with Brew. I've already tried to add the following information in the user.properties file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can you show screenshot? Did you choose Response body tab?

Comment: Updated quesiton. And yes, I am sure I am in the Response Body tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to see Listener response body data in JMeter on MAC OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624576/unable-to-see-listener-response-body-data-in-jmeter-on-mac-os)

Comment: That question does not have a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you've made don't have any impact onto View Results Tree listener output, they are only for .jtl results files.

Try the following:

1. [Run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.xml
   ```

   and open `result.xml` file with your faviourite text or XML viewer/editor. You should see something like:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <testResults version="1.2">
       <httpSample t="93" it="0" lt="93" ct="42" ts="1568029799118" s="true" lb="HTTP Request" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="759" sby="139" ng="1" na="1">
           <responseData class="java.lang.String">{
               &quot;userId&quot;: 1,
               &quot;id&quot;: 1,
               &quot;title&quot;: &quot;delectus aut autem&quot;,
               &quot;completed&quot;: false
               }</responseData>
           <java.net.URL>http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1</java.net.URL>
       </httpSample>

   </testResults>
   ```

   where `responseData` tag contains [XML-escaped](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-escape.html) response data. If there is some data in the file - most probably something is wrong with your JMeter installation, try re-installing it by downloading JMeter from the [official website](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as the Brew package might be broken.
2. Check [`jmeter.log` file contents](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), if anything goes wrong JMeter normally writes a log message with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, but do you have any idea of how to fix the issue in the GUI mode?

Comment: One screenshot is not enough to get to the bottom of the issue, most probably either your JDK or JMeter installation are broken, I cannot reproduce it using Oracle Java 8 and JMeter 5.1.1 from the official websites

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue, and the final answer was to use either Java version 9 or in my case it was Java version 8.  That fixed the issue and I am now able to see the response body and response headers.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you didn't load the generated `*.jtl` file in your "View results Tree" panel. You should browse and open that file and then you can see the results. Remember, you must add the listener, run the tests in non-GUI mode once, and the *.jtl file would then contain the results. Open them here:

[image]

And I think the correct results are not shown.